# How to separate Service layer with Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I want to improve the architecture of my ASP.NET MVC application.
In my controller i use service layer with ViewModel.
Example Service Layer:

```
 public interface ICashRegisterManager
{
    void CreateCashRegister(CashRegisterTransactionModel model, int? programId);
}
```

Example Controller:

```
 public class CashRegisterTransactionController : PersonContextController<CashRegisterTransactionModel, CashRegisterTransactionFilter>
{
    public CashRegisterTransactionController(IPersonContextProvider personContextProvider, ICashRegisterManager cashRegisterManager)
        : base(personContextProvider)
    {
        ExceptionUtil.NotNull(cashRegisterManager, "cashRegisterManager");
        this.cashRegisterManager = cashRegisterManager;
    }

    public override ActionResult Create(DataSourceRequest request, CashRegisterTransactionModel contract)
    {
        cashRegisterManager.CreateCashRegister(contract, contract.ProgramId);
        return base.Create(request, contract);
    }
```

But in Service layer i should to create instance of IRepository and every time map TContract into TEntity.

My idea is in Service layer to use intermediate class , how make this.

Example:

```
  public class CashRegisterManager : ICashRegisterManager
  {
      public void CreateCashRegister(CashRegisterTransactionModel model, int? programId)
     {
         var persister = Persistence.GetPersister<CashRegisterTransactionModel>();
         persister.Add(model);
      }
   }

  public interface IPersister<TContrct>
  {
    void Add(TContrct model);
  }
```

I don't know how to implement the Add method, which to use IRepository.
I guess that should comply with the naming conventions of TContract and TEnitity(CashRegisterTransactionModel/CashRegisterTransaction) and how can I return a instance of IPersister.
I apologize for my English.
Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: You may find this answer useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338868/how-to-organize-dal-in-asp-net-mvc/28339287#28339287

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think creating your own generic repositories is a waste of time. however, perhaps you could try something like this :

```
public interface IPersister<T>
{
    void Add(T model);
}

public class Persister<T> : IPersister<T>
{
    protected List<T> data;

    public Persister()
    {
        this.data = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T model)
    {
        this.data.Add(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: how is it different from your IPersister? I just renamed to make more sense

Comment: The IPersister work with TContract (ViewModel) while the Repository work with Entity object.

Comment: but they are generic?

Comment: var persister = Persistence.GetPersister<CashRegisterTransactionModel>();
 persister.Add(model); 
In the Add method on IPersister I want to use IRepository<CashRegisterTransaction>

Comment: i've renamed to persister. I dont think I understand what your problem is though

Answer (score 0):

This is simple implementation for IPersister :

```
 public class Persister<TContract, TEntity> : IPersister<TContract, TEntity> where TEntity : class,IDeletableEntity
{

    public Persister(IDeletableEntityRepository<TEntity> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Add(TContract model)
    {
        var entity = Mapper.Map<TContract, TEntity>(model);
        repository.Add(entity);
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }


    public IQueryable<TContract> All<TContract>()
    {
        return repository.All().Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Project().To<TContract>();
    }

    #region Private Members
    private IDeletableEntityRepository<TEntity> repository;
    #endregion
}
```

But I don't want to use TEnitity when creating IPersister, because the mvc project doesn't have a reference to Database Entities.